# Outer join and keeping rows without a match in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have three datasets with some geospatial (US census tract) overlap that I want to combine into one. so far I've used merge vector layers to do this since it keeps even rows that do not have matches in all three of the layers (which I don't think any of the join tools do). the issue is that merge vector layers doesn't join them based on a field value (i.e. census tract), so there are multiple instances of census tracts in the census tract column -- one from each layer that it was found in. I want these to all be on one row. the final layer would look like the result of appending all of the columns from each of the 3 layers, joining them by the census tract column while keeping those without matches. I'll give an example of what's happening and what I'd like to happen
[image]

[image]

and with my knowledge of how to use 'Join' tools like 'Join attributes by field value' the output layer only has the overlap, so when I use 'Join attributes by field value', first with dogs and trees, it gives me

[image]

I'm sure there is a better way but this is where my knowledge and searches have taken me.

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific. Can you show what output you get, and what output you are desiring?

Comment: yes thank you I just edited it to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a `virtual layer` with the following code:

```
SELECT census_tract, max(dogs) as dogs, max(trees) as trees, max(roads) as roads
FROM (
   SELECT census_tract, dogs, NULL AS trees, NULL AS roads
   FROM layer_1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT census_tract, NULL AS dogs, trees, NULL AS roads
   FROM layer_2 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT census_tract, NULL AS dogs, NULL AS trees, roads
   FROM layer_3 ) AS subquery
 GROUP BY census_tract;
```

Beware of blanks within layer and field names, as they can return an error. That's why I always use underscores `_` between words (e.g. layer_1).

After that, you can save it as a vector layer if the performance is too slow working with a virtual layer.

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Comment: you might consider accepting @jpinilla's answer

Comment: Revising the question, I have noticed that not all possible `census_tract` values are in `table_1`, so my first proposed code wouldn't work properly. Please note the edited answer.